# Why Picker allow sibling views to move behind window edges during window resizing

Tags: macos, swiftui

The title of my question completely describe issue. Code very simple. To reproproduce issue just paste it in ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

enum Domain: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    var id: Self { self }
    case us, by, kz, uz, com
}

@State private var selecteddomain: Domain = .com

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        GroupBox {
            HStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Please select appropriate domain:")
                    Picker("domain selector", selection: $selecteddomain) {
                        ForEach(Domain.allCases) { Text($0.rawValue) }
                    }
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .pickerStyle(.radioGroup)
                    .horizontalRadioGroupLayout()
                    Text("url: https://example.\(selecteddomain.rawValue)")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .opacity(0.8)
                }
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            .padding(10)
        } label: {
            Text("Title")
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
        }
    }
    .padding(20)
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

`fixedSize` modifier doesn’t help.

How to fix that?
Thank you.
[Video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/WAx0N-44jds)